# Angular CLI 6.x environment files for a library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've created a library with the new CLI 6.x. I've also created an Angular service inside it and I would like to use different URLs for my dev and prod environment. So I created an `environment.ts` and an `environment.prod.ts` file in my library folder.

```js
//dev
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  url: 'dev-url'
};

//prod
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url: 'prod-url'
};
```

I also added the 'fileReplacements' property to the `angular.json` file:

```js
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [{
      "replace": "projects/tk-shared/src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "projects/tk-shared/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }],
    "project": "projects/tk-shared/ng-package.prod.json"
  }
}
```

Compiling the library with the `ng build tk-shared` works and uses the `dev` settings, however when compiling with `ng build --prod tk-shared` I get the following error:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(fileReplacements).
```

My tip is that the reason is that `tk-shared` has the `projectType: "library"` property in `angular.json`.

Anyway, is it possible to use environment files in a library?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Your library should not manage configuration; the consuming application should pass the library what is needs. A library should be sort of dumb in that sense, but smart enough to know when the configuration it needs hasn't been provided.

Comment: @R.Richards I like your idea. Could you show an example how to do it?

Comment: You can find an example of how to do it [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/53ad0d8c73fbad785787d530f7ef0635e2422406/src/core/firebase.app.module.ts); this is for Firebase. Specifically, look at how they implement/use their `initializeApp` function. All the details are in their code. Have fun!

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks for the tip, I managed to figure it out. It's an elegant solution!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks, @R. Richards for pointing me to the right solution!
These two sources helped me figure out how to do this injection correctly: [LINK1](https://arturas.smorgun.com/2017/06/08/inject-environment-configuration-into-service-in-angular4.html) and [LINK2](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/360).

So what I did ...

Created an `InjectionToken` and modified my `TkSharedModule`:

```js
export const BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('BASE_URL');
//...
export class TkSharedModule {
  static forRoot(host: string) {
    return {
      ngModule: TkSharedModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: BASE_URL,
        useValue: host
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Provided a value for this token from the `environment` files in my `AppModule`:

```js
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
//...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TkSharedModule.forRoot(environment.url)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally injected this value in my service:

```js
//MyServiceService

import { BASE_URL } from '../tk-shared.module';

constructor(@Inject(BASE_URL) BASE_URL: string) {
  console.log('base url', BASE_URL);
}
```

Comment: Is this approach possible if you want to use what's being passed into the `forRoot` method in the `NgModule` decorator of the library module/project?

Comment: Do you mean the value of environment.url? If so, then yes, because in the service of the library, BASE_URL will have the value of environment.url.

Comment: But I'm talking about using it in the `NgModule` decorator, not an internal service of the library.

Comment: @JakeSmith, any luck finding out how to do that?

Comment: @jeti: using angular 12 it is required to declare forRoot return type: `  static forRoot(host: string): ModuleWithProviders<TkSharedModule> {`